# Why does useEffect dependencies on destructed props cause maximum update exceeded?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, use-effect, object-destructuring

I got the problem with following code:

```js
function Test1(props) {
  const { ids = [] } = props;
  const [evenIds, setEvenIds] = useState<string[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const newEvenIds = ids.filter(id => id % 2 === 0);
    setEvenIds(newEvenIds);
  }, [ids])

  return (<span>hello</span>)
}
```

The code above uses the `useEffect` hook listening changes of props. When this component is used as `<Test1 ids={[]}/>`, everything seems to be fine. However, if it is used as `<Test1 />` without passing props, the console repeatedly reports the error `maximum update depth exceeded` and the browser crashes finally.

I guess that the variable `ids` with initial value `undefined`, is assigned `[]`, which causes `useEffect` to run. But how does that leads to the repeated error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `ids` is passed as a prop, the only time the local `ids` variable will have had its reference changed will be when the prop changes.

When it's not passed as a prop, the default assignment, since it runs inside the function, every time the function runs, produces a new empty array every time. So, if the function component updates *once*, it'll try to continue updating forever because the default empty array reference keeps changing.

One way to fix this would be to put the empty array outside the component. (Just make sure not to mutate, as always in React)

```
const emptyArr = [];
function Test1(props) {
  const { ids = emptyArr } = props;
  const [evenIds, setEvenIds] = useState<string[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const newEvenIds = ids.filter(id => id % 2 === 0);
    setEvenIds(newEvenIds);
  }, [ids])

  return (<span>hello</span>)
}
```

State shouldn't be duplicated in more than one place though. `useMemo` would be more appropriate than a separate state and `useEffect` IMO.

```
const emptyArr = [];
function Test1(props) {
  const { ids = emptyArr } = props;
  const evenIds = useMemo(() => ids.filter(id => id % 2 === 0), [ids]);
  return (<span>hello</span>)
}
```

Comment: IMO the workaround adds a lot of noise. Why not make the dependency on `props.ids` and get rid of the early destructuring? At least in the example, it's not being used anywhere else. It may look simpler to destructure a couple lines ahead, but not when it requires so much bloat to make it work as expected.

Comment: The other alternative is to not use a default initialiser in the destructuring and put the default value inside the `useMemo`, like `const evenIds = useMemo(() => (ids ?? []).filter(id => id % 2 === 0), [ids]);` (or `ids ? ids.filter(…) : []` etc).

Comment: @Ezra There's not enough context in the question IMO, I wouldn't want to remove the `ids` entirely in case OP wanted to use that in his actual code. Yeah, if he's really not using it anywhere other than compute the evens, it'd be better to remove it entirely (but in the toy example he isn't even using the `evenIds` that've been constructed either)... it's not clear what's actually going to be used later.

Comment: @CertainPerformance since this effect/memo relies on `props.ids`, it might as well communicate that. Definitely agree that there isn't enough context to not be bike-shedding, but it still feels dirty to create an out-of-scope initial value as a workaround, unless it's ends up being the official exported default for destructuring arrays.

Comment: Thanks. But for one last question, what does that mean "State shouldn't be duplicated in more than one place"? For the demo posted in question, I am using one state and modified it only once

Comment: @kayochin In some cases, the ids will be passed from the parent component, in which case they'll likely be stored in the parent component's state somehow - in which case a duplicate dependent state in the child component probably isn't the best approach. It's not *forbidden*, but IMO it's a bit of a code smell and can make some things a bit more difficult than they'd be otherwise

Answer (score -1):

Is not because of the destructed props. You are using one array like the value.

```
const { ids = [] } = props;
```

If you want to use the value as an array, try to use it this way in your useEffect;

```
[JSON.stringfy(ids)]
```

The useEffect verify the value inside the variable and tests if the value changes or not. But you need to put one primal value inside. If you want, you can use ids[0] to get one value if this array has primal values in all positions.